# Equivalence vs equisatisfiability

Tags: logic, model-theory

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skolem_normal_form) page states that first order formula after skolemization is equisatisfiable but not equivalent to original one. I do not understand what the difference is. Here is Wikipedia's definition:

> Two formulae are equisatisfiable if either both formulae are
> satisfiable or both are not. Two equisatisfiable formulae may have
> different models. As a result, equisatisfiability is different from
> logical equivalence, as two equivalent formulae always have the same
> models.

Question is how can it be that something is not equivalent but equisatisfiable.

Comment: The difference is clearly explained [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equisatisfiability).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In oder to "manufacture" a counterexample for two formuale being *equisatisfiable* but not *equivalent*, consider the first-order language of arithmetic with the predicate $<$ ("less-than") and a new (unary) function symbol $f$, and let :

$\phi := \forall x \exists y (x < y), \psi := \forall x (x < f(x))$.

The two are satisfiable in the same model, considering $\mathbb N$ and interpreting $<^N = <$ and $f^N: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ being the addition $x \mapsto x+1$.

However, they are not equivalent, i.e. there is another model where one is true and the other is not: consider again $\mathbb N$ and interpret the function symbol $f$ with : $f^N : \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ such that $f^N(n)=0$, for all $n \in \mathbb N$. In this model, $x < f(x)$ is false.

In fact: $\forall x (x < f(x)) \vDash \forall x \exists y (x < y)$ but $\forall x \exists y (x < y) \nvDash \forall x (x < f(x))$.

Comment: So let me get this straight: equivalence means they're equivalent in *every* model. Equisatisfiable means they're both true in *some* model. Is that right?

Comment: @goblinGONE no, it means "if A has a model, so does B, and vice versa" take for example, in the language $<$, $φ:=(\text{$<$ is a strict total order}+\text{ there exists a minimum, but no maximum})$ and $ψ:=(\text{$<$ is a strict total order}+\text{ there exists no minimum, but a maximum})$, no model of $φ$ is a model of $ψ$, and no model of $ψ$ is a model of $φ$, but if $φ$ has a model, $ψ$ also has a model and if $ψ$ has a model, so does $φ$, so $φ$ and $ψ$ are equisatisfiable