# Are two formulae $\phi = p, \psi = \neg p$ equisatisfiable?

Tags: logic, satisfiability

Two formulae $\phi$ and $\psi$ are equisatisfiable if both of them are satisfiable or none of them is satisfiable. And they can have their own independent truth assignments $\tau_{1}$ and $\tau_{2}$ such that $\tau_{1}$ assigns True to $\phi$ and $\tau_{2}$ assigns True to $\psi$, they need not be True on the same truth assignment $\tau$.

But in the answer given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1060676/equivalence-vs-equisatisfiability/1060724#1060724), it is said that Equsatisfiability means- The two formulae are satisfiable if there is a model in which both are true. Isn't it incorrect?

So according to my understanding p and ~p are equisatisfiable, aren't they?

Comment: Correct; the general definition equisat is "either both formulae are satisfiable or both are not. " In general we can have two sentences that are true in the same model but not equivalent, also in prop logic: $p$ and $p \lor q$. Obviously, with a contradictory pair $p, \lnot p$ we cannot satisfy them in the same model.

Comment: Are you claiming that $p$ and $\lnot p$ are always equisatisfiable? What if $p$ is a tautology?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wikipedia : "two formulae are equisatisfiable if the first formula is satisfiable **whenever** the second is". In order that $p$ and $\neg p$ to be equisatisfiable a very weak interpretation of whenever must be adopted.

Wikipedia: "Equisatisfiability is generally used in the context of translating formulae,"  examples "Skolemization" and "translations into conjunctive normal form". In these examples the interpretation of **whenever** could be asymmetric. In any model that the first  sentence is satisfiable the second sentence is satisfiable.

I am no expert and would be delighted to be corrected. But I find it hard to believe that when people say  "Skolemization results in equisatisfiable sentences not equivalent sentences" that they are adopting such a weak interpretation of equisatisfiable.

As symmetry is implied in the Wiki description of equisatisfiable we could take a reasonably standard approach (In category theory adjunctions are frequently interpreted as weak equalities) and interpret equisatisfiable to imply the existence of a Galois mapping connecting the two sentences. Then the asymmetry caused by one term containing a superset of non-logical functions can be modeled by requiring the Galois connection be a retract (a Galois connection with  one sided inverse)
regards david